# Change the data name in json

Tags: json, reactjs

I receive a category list:

```
0:
name: "Acessórios para Veículos"
uuid: "d87506-bb-08-d0-58c2d4af"
1:
name: "Agro, Indústria e Comércio"
uuid: "d87507-bb-07-d0-57c2d4af"
```

The component I am using does not identify the given name and uuid.

I wanted to leave it this way:

```
0:
label: "Acessórios para Veículos"
value: "d87506-bb-08-d0-58c2d4af"
1:
label: "Agro, Indústria e Comércio"
value: "d87507-bb-07-d0-57c2d4af"
```

Select:

```
<Select name="category" data={CategoryList} label="Categoria" onChange={handleCategoryChange} />
```

How do I change this on the front end?

Comment: Please include the code from your component used to read the JSON data.

Comment: Are you using react-select?

Comment: The component I'm using is from a private library of the company I work for, but I added the way I call the list of categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Shmili told before, and if your data is an Array of objects, you can make like this:

```
<Select 
  name="category" 
  data={CategoryList.map(({name, uuid}) => ({label:name, value:uuid})} 
  label="Categoria" 
  onChange={handleCategoryChange} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map thorough all items and get back a new array with the correct names like this:

```
let modified = categories.map(cat => {
    {label: cat.name, value:cat.uuid}
})
```

Comment: I think it might be faster to `JSON.stringify` the data, then replace the keys using regular expression, then `JSON.parse` the string back to an object.  Of course, even if I'm right, it would be negligible if the data is small.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I ran a test and here is a screenshot of the result https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuwOysPxjRnLyTqJ3AnEvuRTsPWp , (there may be a better way to write the solution you suggested, I tried my best).